# What do we know about Yune's father?

Tags: ikoku-meiro-no-croisee

I've read the first few chapters of the Ikoku Meiro no Croisée manga. In these chapters, we hear a little about Yune's mother, and a little about her older sister, but I don't remember anything being mentioned about her father. Do we ever hear anything about him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very little. In fact, we know very little about Yune's family in general, or what she was doing in Nagasaki when Oscar found her.

In Chapter 1 of the manga, Oscar mentions meeting Yune's father, but doesn't elaborate. We only hear about her mother early on when she gives Claude her mother's kimono to sell. It's implied that her mother is dead. We hear the most about Yune's older sister Shione, and even see her a few times in Yune's flashbacks. In the anime, Yune remembers Shione singing to her, tending her in an illness, and doing shadow puppets with her hands through the door.

In Yune's flashbacks, the house we see appears to be a large mansion, so it seems probable that Yune's parents were either nobility or somehow affiliated with nobility. The beautiful kimono that Yune inherited from her mother also implies wealth.

The manga ends without ever telling us anything more about Yune's family, so this seems to be all we can ever know.

(Early on, I suspected we'd find that Yune was Oscar's love child from a forbidden dalliance with a Japanese woman, but I no longer think that likely.)